# Probability of red-flowering independent of other plants

Tags: probability

According to genetic theory, plants of a particular species have a $25%$ chance of being red-flowering, independently of other plants. Find the normal approximation to the chance that among $10,000$ plants of this species, more than $2400$ are red-flowering.

The event is more than $24%$ red-flowering.

Law of Large Numbers:

As the number of trials (plants) goes up, the proportion of red-flowering plants approaches $p = 0.25$;

$n=100$

$Mean=μ=np= (10000)*(0.25)=2500$

$\sigma=\sqrt{n*p*(1−p)}=\sqrt{10,000×0.25×0.75}=43.30$

$z=\frac{X−\mu}{\sigma}$

$z=\frac{2400−2500}{43.30}=−2.31$

Area under the normal curve $98.96%= 0.9896$

Comment: Seems basically fine. The remark about Law of Large Numbers not needed. You have $n=100$, but that may be a typo for $10000$. Or maybe not, sometimes it looks as if you are counting by hundreds. Number looks about right.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about what the question wants. You want $P(X> 2400)$ when $X$ follows a binomial distribution with $p=0.25$ and $N=10000$.

You need a normal approximation $Y$ to $X$ - that is, you should match the mean and variance of $Y$ to those of $X$. Then you can approximate your answer using $P(Y>2400)$.